# Исходный код Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, opensource

Все знают, что Google Chrome - браузер с открытым исходным кодом, т.е OpenSource. Корпорация Google даже организовывает конкурсы, в которых участники ищут баги в исходном коде. Багов с момента выхода самой первой версии браузера было исправлено очень много: и серьёзных и не особо( Null-Byte в адресной строке, например ).

Так вот, хотелось бы взглянуть на исходный код браузера и попытаться что-либо понять в нем =). Посмотреть, как бравые разработчики гугла реализовали те или иные вещи...но исходники браузера я нигде найти не могу, даже на самом сайте разработчика( google.com ) выдается [404 ошибка](http://www.chromium.org/intl/ru/). Может кто уже скачивал исходники и смотрел? В таком случае хотелось бы узнать, откуда вы скачивали.

Comment: Я думаю, пора объявлять конкурс, в котором участники осилят добраться до кода.

Comment: Ахах, смешно =)

Answer (score 4):

Идите по [этому](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/) адресу и изучайте материалы. Сам исходный код в режиме онлайн можно посмотреть [тут](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/search)

Comment: Благодарю.

Answer (score 4):

Собственно [вот](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) так вот можно получить исходник chromium ( именно на основе *chromium*, был написан *google chrome* ).

Так-же, не менее интересно, копаться в исходниках *webkit* и *v8*

Comment: Спасибо. Вот только хотелось бы именно сам исходник браузера. И, кстати, сам движок V8 разве не полностью встроен в Google Chrome?

Comment: @Asen - полностью встроен, но все и сразу осилить не представляется возможным.

Comment: Да, модулей в браузере и правда очень много, а в каждом модуле еще букет файлов с кодом...1.6 ГБ, как-никак.