# Chrome opensource

Tags: google-chrome, opensource

Где найти исходный код Chrome?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Исходный код Google Chrome](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/121283/%d0%98%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-google-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хром сделан на базе [Chromium](http://dev.chromium.org/Home):

> This site contains design documents, architecture overviews, testing information, and more to help you learn to build and work with the Chromium source code.